# Problems with conversion of multilinestring to linestring

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geocoding

I'm trying to convert a column of datatype multilinestring to linestring using sql:

```
ALTER TABLE streets_nordeste
ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(linestring,3857) USING ST_GeometryN(geom, 1);
```

But the result is:

```
ERROR: Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (3857)
SQL state: 22023
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the SRID like this:

```
ALTER TABLE streets_nordeste
ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(linestring,3857)
USING ST_SetSRID(ST_GeometryN(geom, 1),3857);
```